# How to use quickblox for web

Tags: java, javascript, quickblox

I want to use quickblox for chat. I want to use quickblox rest api. But I don't understand how can I achieve this. 
I tried to follow the tutorial given in http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript

But I am not able to understand how to configure this

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not use JavaScript SDK for web?

I suggest you to use JavaScript SDK for real time chat application and documentation is also very good for JavaScript SDK

**Go thought this link:"https://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript"**

Hope this help you.